# access session value during concurrent requests

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session

I have following problem.

in one request i am updating session variable.
in the other request, i am trying to access that session value, but it was blocked until the first request finish.

I am using C# with ASP.NET 2.0

**UPDATE**:

My page code looks like this.

```
while(int progress = DoWork() && progress <= 100 ){
    Session["Progress"] = progress;
}
```

and my handler just return Session value.

```
context.Response.Write(Session["progress"].toString());
context.Response.End();
```

Comment: This sounds like the same problem I asked about in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749532

Answer (score 1):

You really should not be running concurrent calls with ASP.net due to the nature of how the apps are developed. This sounds like a normal locking mechanism , the only thing you can really do is cater for a lock and just keep the thread waiting till the other thread is done.

If possible post some code as to what you are running multiple threads at the same time , there maybe a better way to do it.